# How to get further of Checkout page in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on `woocommerce wordpress plugin`.  My project is located at the link :

http://tiffinkaku.com/planner/

When I add any product in `cart` go to the `checkout page`

When I select `Cash on delivery` and click on `Place order` then it doesnt go further only the link goes blur

How can I come out to the situation ?

Comment: You have a javascript error, check your console.

Comment: About 9 out of 10 times you can trace it to a theme compatibility problem.

Comment: Now I have resolved the jquery Problem but getting the same problem